# How to write this aggregation query in spring data mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

How to implement this query in spring data mongoDB using MongoTemplate
find number of suggestions in a document with particular id.

Query:

```
b.node.aggregate(
    {
        $match:
              {"id":"a"}
    },
    {
    $project: {
         count: { $size:"$sugg" },
            "_id":0
        }
    }
)
```

Schema:

```
{
    "id":"a",
    "sugg":[
        {
            "w":"a",
            "f":1
        },
        {
            "w":"b",
            "f":1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This should be pretty straightforward.You can find spring aggregation examples [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation)